# Set maximum of datapoints per plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Im using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import pandas as pandas
from datetime import datetime

dataset = pandas.read_csv("HugLog_17.01.11.csv", sep=",", header=0)

print('filter data for SrcAddr')
dataset_filtered = dataset[dataset['SrcAddr']=='0x1FD3']

print('get Values')
varY = dataset_filtered.Battery_Millivolt.values

varX = dataset_filtered.Timestamp.values

print('Convert the date-strings in date-objects.')
dates_list = [datetime.strptime(date, '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for date in varX]

fig = pyplot.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.set_xlabel('Time')
ax1.set_ylabel('Millivolt')
ax1.bar(dates_list, varY)

pyplot.locator_params(axis='x',nbins=10)

pyplot.show()
```

The problem i have is, its a large datacollection with 180k datapoints.

And pyplot displays all points an the graph which makes it slow and the bars overlap. Is there a way to set a maximum-limit on how much datapoints a displayed at a "view".

What i mean by that is, that as soon as the graph is render ther are only 50 datapoints and when i zoomm in i only get a maximum of 50 datapoints again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resampling can be done with the [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html?highlight=resample#pandas.DataFrame.resample) function from pandas.

Note that the `resample` syntax has changed between version 0.17 and 0.19 of pandas. The example below uses the old style. See e.g. [this tutorial](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#resampling) for the new style.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate some data for every second over a whole day
times = pd.date_range(start='2017-01-11',periods=86400, freq='1S')
df = pd.DataFrame(index = times)
df['data'] = np.sort(np.random.randint(low=1300, high=1600, size=len(df.index)) )[::-1] + \
             np.random.rand(len(df.index))*100

# resample the data, taking the mean over 1 hours ("H")
t = "H" # for hours, try "T" for minutes as well
width=1./24 #matplotlib default uses a width of 1 day per bar
                 # try width=1./(24*60) for minutes
df_resampled = pd.DataFrame()
df_resampled['data'] = df.data.resample(t, how="mean")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

#ax.bar(df.index, df['data'], width=1./(24*60*60)) # original data, takes too long to plot
ax.bar(df_resampled.index, df_resampled['data'], width=width)
ax.xaxis_date()

plt.show()
```

Automatic adaption of the resampling when zooming would indeed require some manual work. There is a [resampling example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/resample.html) on the matplotlib event handling page, which does not work out of the box but could be adapted accordingly.

This is how it would look like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import matplotlib.dates

class Sampler():
    def __init__(self,df):
        self.df = df

    def resample(self, limits):
        print limits
        dt = limits[1] - limits[0]
        if (type(dt) != pd.tslib.Timedelta) and (type(dt) != datetime.timedelta):
            dt = datetime.timedelta(days=dt)
        print dt
        #see #http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases
        if dt > datetime.timedelta(hours=5):
            t = "H"; width=1./24
        elif dt > datetime.timedelta(minutes=60):
            t = "15T"; width=15./(24.*60)
        elif dt > datetime.timedelta(minutes=5):
            t = "T"; width=1./(24.*60)
        elif dt > datetime.timedelta(seconds=60):
            t = "15S"; width=15./(24.*60*60)
        else: 
            #dt < datetime.timedelta(seconds=60):
            t = "S"; width=1./(24.*60*60)

        self.resampled = pd.DataFrame()
        self.resampled['data'] = self.df.data.resample(t, how="mean")
        print t, len(self.resampled['data'])
        print "indextype",  type(self.resampled.index[0])
        print "limitstype",  type(limits[1])
        if type(limits[1]) == float or type(limits[1]) == np.float64 :
            dlowlimit = matplotlib.dates.num2date(limits[0])
            duplimit = matplotlib.dates.num2date(limits[1])
            print type(duplimit), duplimit
            self.resampled = self.resampled.loc[self.resampled.index <= duplimit]
            self.resampled = self.resampled.loc[self.resampled.index >= dlowlimit]
        else:
            self.resampled = self.resampled.loc[self.resampled.index <= limits[1]]
            self.resampled = self.resampled.loc[self.resampled.index >= limits[0]]
        return self.resampled.index,self.resampled['data'],width

    def update(self, ax):
        print "update"
        lims = ax.viewLim
        start, stop = lims.intervalx
        ax.clear()
        x,y,width = self.resample([start, stop])
        ax.bar(x,y, width=width)
        ax.set_xlim([start, stop])
        ax.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed', self.update)
        ax.figure.canvas.draw()




times = pd.date_range(start='2017-01-11',periods=86400, freq='1S')
df = pd.DataFrame(index = times)
df['data'] = np.sort(np.random.randint(low=1300, high=1600, size=len(df.index)) )[::-1] + \
             np.random.rand(len(df.index))*500


sampler = Sampler(df)
x,y,width = sampler.resample( [df.index[0],df.index[-1] ] )


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(x,y, width=width)
ax.xaxis_date()

# connect to limits changes
ax.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed', sampler.update)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I adapted the resample function from the matplotlib example page to fit to the problem of plotting dates/times.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is plot a random subset of the data by using the `sample` method on your pandas DataFrame. Use the `frac` argument to determine the fraction of points you want to use. It ranges from 0 to 1.

After you get your `dataset_filtered` DataFrame, take a sample of it like this

```
dataset_filtered_sample = dataset_filtered.sample(frac=.001)
```

Comment: When i understand this correctly sample will pick items at random which is not what i want. i want them evenly distributed. It would also be nice if the graph would do that and not be forced to do it by hand so the zooming in/out would automaticaly update. Thanks anyway for the fast answer.